# Why is chromedriver tied to chrome version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm starting to use selenium and ChromeDriver in order to automate tasks in Chrome. I'm interested in scaling the task across multiple managed windows PC's.

I understand that updates of Chrome might break functionality in ChromeDriver. But I'm concerned it's the right tool because manually updating based on the chrome version results in a lot of maintenance as we'd have to manually place the executable on each system.

Is ChromeDriver really "whitelisting" with which chrome version it works? and why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers would have updates, which the driver also must have in order to invoke and interact with the browser, and hence your driver version must be in sync with the browser version. It is not just for Chrome, but for Firefox, and Edge also. One thing you can do is to use the ChromeDriverManager by installing the webdriver-manager library.
In Python, you do like this:
`pip install webdriver-manager`

In the py file, you can invoke the chromedriver:
`from webdriver_manager import ChromeDriverManager`

Then, when you initialize the driver, you can pass in the ChromeDriverManager:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

With this, your driver and browser would be in sync. You need not worry about the incompatibility of driver-browser versions.

Please note: you would get a depcration warning with the above `driver` line of code, for which you need to include `Service` object; however, for now, it is a warning and not an error, so your code would not hamper the execution, but sooner or later, you must use `Service` object.

Here is a good article you can refer to [Medium](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/webdriver-manager-resolve-compatibility-issues-in-selenium-python-bef18c204475)

Comment: so, the driver is not just talking to chrome via some interface but has a deeper integration that needs to be changed every version update?

Comment: You may find good details here: [SO Archive Link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28358/how-does-chromedriver-exe-work-on-a-core-and-fundamental-level)

Although, it says JSON Wire Protocol;  with the release of Selenium4, Selenium Webdriver uses W3C protocol instead of JSON Wire Protocol.